# How to remove a pattern in JS Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, alert, confirm

The following code hides all webpages of a certain website and mocks the website.

```
let sites = ['mako.co.il', 'walla.co.il'];

for (let i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(sites[i]) != -1 ) {

    alert(` Enough with this ${sites[i]} garbage! `);
    }
}
```

It displays domain.tld this way:

> "Enough with this domain.tld garbage!".

How could I strip away the `.tld`, so the final outcome would be:

> "Enough with this domain garbage!".

A `/[domain]@.2,/` regex might unmatch tld's like `.com` or `co.uk` and only "domain" will appear on the alert, but I don't know how to implement such regex to the `sites[i]` in the confirm.

Do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how complex your strings can get, but a simple match for domains could be something as follows:

```
str.replace(/(\.[a-zA-Z]{1,3}){1,2}/, '')
```

This will work for most examples of "domain.com", "domain.co.uk", "domain.es". You might be able to find a better regex, but the idea would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Need to say, that **it's a long and ugly way**, but I want to show you, that it's possible without regex:

```js
function splitDomain(str) {
  var beforeDomain = str.split(" domain");
  var afterDomain = beforeDomain[1].split(" ").splice(1, 1);
  beforeDomain.splice(1, 1);
  beforeDomain.push("domain")
  afterDomain.forEach(function(item) {
    beforeDomain.push(item);
  })
  var final = beforeDomain.join(" ")
  console.log(final);
}

splitDomain("Enough with this domain.tld shit!");
splitDomain("Enough with this domain.co.uk shit!");
splitDomain("Enough with this domain.com shit!");
```